# Clearing header on specific ordinally numbered pages of each chapter

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, reledpar

I'm using `reledpar` and `fancyhdr` to lay out something in `book` class. I've got `\thispagestyle{empty}` at the opening of each chapter, but I need to clear the header (though not the footer) of the second and third pages of each chapter as well. Any thoughts on how to do it?

(Note: If there's no other way to do it I'm happy (solve for some value of "happy") to hack it by doing specific page number exceptions, but I can't figure out how to do that either.)

Here's what I hope is a MWE—I'm new to LaTeX so there are some thing in the template I'm using whose function isn't yet entirely clear to me. If there are things I should remove, just let me know and I gladly will.

```
\documentclass[openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[CFE,CFO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\itshape\ Heading Left }
\fancyhead[CO]{\itshape\ Heading Right}

\begin{document}
\chapter{I}
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{pages}
        \begin{Leftside}
            \beginnumbering
                        \pstart
Chapter Title Left \par
                        \normalfont
                \pend
                \pstart
Body text left.

\pend
            \endnumbering
        \end{Leftside}
        \begin{Rightside}
            \beginnumbering
                    \pstart
Chapter Title Right \par
                        \normalfont
                \pend
                \pstart
Body text right.

\pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}

\end{pages} 
\Pages
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

So in the four-page document my MWE produces, I want a header on page 4 and page 4 only. Ideally I'd have page numbers on each of pages 2-4 and no page number on page 1, but I could live with a page number on 4 and 4 only.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your request. Reproducing the request and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.``

Comment: Thank you so much—I'll put one together. Should I delete the question for now and then repost once I've got it (it's going to be at least a few hours)?

Comment: It is not required: use the "edit" button below the text of the question to add your MWE

Comment: Added the MWE! Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: You are welcome! remember also to [upvote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up)/[accept](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) the answers that helped you the most ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `\fancypagestyle` to create new page styles if `empty` and `plain` are not quite what you wanted.

```
\documentclass[openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[CFE,CFO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\itshape\ Heading Left }
\fancyhead[CO]{\itshape\ Heading Right}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand{\mypagestyle}{\thispagestyle{empty}\afterpage{\thispagestyle{plain}\afterpage{\thispagestyle{plain}}}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\mypagestyle}{}{xpatch failure}

\begin{document}
\chapter{I}
%\mypagestyle% test run
    \begin{pages}
        \begin{Leftside}
            \beginnumbering
                        \pstart
Chapter Title Left \par
                        \normalfont
                \pend
                \pstart
Body text left.

\pend
            \endnumbering
        \end{Leftside}
        \begin{Rightside}
            \beginnumbering
                    \pstart
Chapter Title Right \par
                        \normalfont
                \pend
                \pstart
Body text right.

\pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}

\end{pages} 
\Pages
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much—this both fixes my problem AND gives me stuff to research and learn about—the best of both worlds!

Comment: Thanks John, I have not to answer to this reledpar question. I am happy for it :)

Comment: John, this was working so beautifully for me and then, when I had to switch from `reledpar` to `paracol` I could only get halfway there. If you're so inclined, would you mind taking a look at my new question about it at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544378/pagestyleplain-after-beginning-of-chapter-showing-up-as-pagestylefancy ? Thanks either way for the help here!